# Refreshing page after remote => true modal form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a Modal with form and after submitting it with no validation error i'm trying to close Modal and refresh page with new results. But i can't get it to work. I have this code (Rails 3):

My Controller:

```
    def create

    @stuff = Stuff.new(params[:stuff])

       respond_to do |format|
          if @stuff.save
             format.js 
          else
             format.js
          end
       end
     end
```

_addModal.html.erb

```
<div id="addModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Label</h3>
    </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>
                <fieldset>
                <label></label>
                <%= render 'form2' %>    
                </fieldset>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

_form2.html.erb

```
%= form_for(@stuff, :remote => true) do |f| %>

   <% if @stuff.errors.any? %>
     <div id="error_explanation">
       <div class="alert">
          <h2><%= @stuff.errors.count %></h2>

        <ul>
          <% @stuff.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
           <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
               <% end %>

     <%= f.label :name %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :name %>


    <%= f.submit %>

  <% end %>
```

create.js.erb

```
<%- if @stuff.errors.any? %>

           $('#addModal').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "form2") %>');

           <%- else %>

          $('#addModal').modal('hide').empty();


          <%- end %>
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Thanks!

**Update:**

Also i got few quetions:
1) In case there are validation errors create.js.erb returns new Modal with 'form2' content only- without #addModal layout. How can i fix it?

2) How can clear form after successful submision?

Comment: Is there any error or something in your terminal while trying this?

Comment: i dont see any problem with your code. do you just want to know how to refresh the page?

Comment: There is no error. But when i submit form it just closes and i need to refresh page manualy to see new results in view table. I want to do this automaticly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this in your js.erb file to reload the page automatically

```
<%- if @stuff.errors.any? %>
  $('#addModal').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "form2") %>');
<%- else %>
  $('#addModal').modal('hide').empty();
  window.location.reload();
<%- end %>
```

Comment: And how can i reload not whole page, but just one partial i.e. _table.html.erb inside view?

Comment: same thing you did with the form partial in your code when @stuff has errors

Comment: But what should i apply '.html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "table") %>');' to ? To window.location ?

Comment: determine the part of the html page that you want to replace with the table partial.  is it the body of the html? or just a div inside it? if you can answer this, that's where you apply that code.

Comment: And the last question: How can i clear form every time after Modal close - no matter successful or error? Thanks

Comment: try `$('form').find('input, textarea').val('')`